# Convert MS Outlook formatted email addresses to names of attendees using RegEx

Tags: regex, email, outlook, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepadd ++ to find and replace regex to extract names from MS Outlook formatted meeting attendee details.

I copy and pasted the attendee details and got names like.

> `Fred Jones <Fred.Jones@example.org.au>; Bob Smith <Bob.Smith@example.org.au>; Jill Hartmann <Jill.Hartmann@example.org.au>;`

I'm trying to wind up with

> `Fred Jones; Bob Smith; Jill Hartmann;`

I've tried a number of permutations of

```
\B<.*>; \B
```

on Regex 101.

Comment: I edited to use a domain name which is reserved for examples. Most TLDs have `example.tld` reserved for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is greedy, `<.*>` matches from the first `<` to the last `>` in one fell swoop. You want to say "any character which is neither of these" instead of just "any character".

```
 *<[^<>]*>
```

The single space and asterisk before the main expression consumes any spaces before the match. Replace these matches with nothing and you will be left with just the names, like in your example.

This is a very common FAQ.

Comment: Explanation: The small spaceship which is taking off from the landing bay of the big spaceship with blinkenlights is winking back at it.